# Extracting href links from multiple directories on a page

Tags: php, json, hyperlink, href

I am using a Javascript JFlot Graph to monitor a list of .rrd files I have on my server. I hard coded all the .rrd file href links into the JavaScript code of of the Graph in a drop down menu. I then realized it was bad practice to hard code them in.

Here comes the problem.

I want to write some code that each time I open the Graph, would check the server or the page, for all the .rrd files, extract them as href links, and place them inside 'something' so that the JavaScript 'drop down menu' for the Graph could read it.

I researched there was two solutions to do this, 1. Using client-side programing via JQuery and Ajax (I am not cross domain coding) 2. Server-Side via PHP and Json.

I figured Server-Side was the better option, for the understanding that it's easier and that the code wont need to download anything, regardless if it would only take a few seconds.

I just could not figure out the solution to this problem yet. I hope I explained my problem well and any advice or code is welcome, including any good practices to abide by or whether to use option 1 by extracting it from the directories on the page or 2 collecting the data from the server.

Thank You for your time and consideration I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Depending on how much traffic your website gets, generating the list of files every time the page is called can take up a good bit of resources.

Comment: Right I figured as much, however, I use the Graph for very detailed and analytical data, and it's important that I know that all the files are up to date. Would it be better to grab the data from the page rather then the server? (I was getting into problems grabbing the data from the page because of the way apache works).

Answer (score 1):

As long as all the files are in one directory, you can generate the list pretty easily using PHP's `glob` function:

`$files = glob($storage_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.rrd');`

It returns an array where each entry is a file name.  You can easily convert this to JSON and send it back using:

`$response = json_encode($files);`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check that now.

Comment: Yes it is in one directory. I am not using your code correctly because it is not working, would it be possible for you to explain to me how to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: `glob` returns an array of file names based on the filter you specify.  In this case, we ask it for all .rrd files from the directory defined by `$storage_dir`.  If this script were to be called by javascript and the returned data is expected to be in json format, then you'd output the result of passing the file name array to `json_encode`.

Comment: Thank You. Still working on this project. I appreciate your help.